# Elasticsearch mappings doesn't seem to apply for query

Tags: elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch with Spring Boot application. In this application there 
I have index `customer`, and customer contains field secretKey. This secret key is string that is build from numbers and letters in way `FOOBAR-000`

My goal was to select exactly one customer by his secret key, so I changed mappings to NOT ANALYZE that fields but it seems not to work. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my mapping

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/customer/_mapping'
 {
        "customer": {
            "mappings": {
                "customer": {
                    "properties": {
                        "secretKey": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but after I will run query

```
curl -XGET "http:/localhost:9200/customer/_validate/query?explain" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
        "query": "FOOBAR-3121"
    }
   }
}'
```

I get following explanation:

```
"explanations": [
        {
            "index": "customer",
            "valid": true,
            "explanation": "_all:foobar _all:3121"
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you have an index called "*customer*" and within this index, a document containing a "*customer* field. In your case the secretKey should be nested in the "*customer*" field. For some reasons Elasticsearch decided to have a strange behaviour if you encapsulate objects without specifying that they are of nested type. [This is the article from the doc that explains the behaviour in details.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) If you specify it with the following :

```
{
    "customer": {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
              "properties": {
                  "customer": {
                     "type": "nested" 
                   }
              }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Then it should work with your query

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify field name in your query, without it ElasticSearch executes query against all field, so you see _all . Try this one:

```
curl -XGET "http:/localhost:9200/customer/_validate/query?explain" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "secretKey": {
        "value": "FOOBAR-3121"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> My goal was to select exactly one customer by his secret key

Your requirement is strict, so use MATCH query to select ONLY matched customer!

```
curl -XGET "http:/localhost:9200/customer/_validate/query?explain" -d'
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
          "secretKey": "FOOBAR-3121"
     }
 }
```